# Roads not showing in Google Earth Pro

Tags: layers, google-earth, road

The road names are no longer showing on my Google Earth Pro. The only general layers available in the bottom left  panel are "primary Database " and "terrain".

I have tried turning Google Earth Pro on and off / tried removing a stack of folders in 'my places', checked my computer storage has free disc space, shut down the computer.

Can anyone help?

Comment: HI, are you using it in a web browser or on desktop? I would either clear your browsing data or reinstall google earth pro. It's possible that you'll find better advice at the google community for Earth than you will here where it's not a very common platform. https://support.google.com/earth/community?hl=en

Comment: thanks -i don't know - its loaded onto my laptop computer. I don't know that i want to re-install as i want to keep my places - i have a lot stored that i regularly use. 
Any other options that wouldn't lose my places ? Is there a way to store them all in case i lose them?

Comment: Since Sue mentions "Google Earth Pro", then this is the desktop version (Earth v7), not web/mobile (Earth v9).

Comment: Sue, this issue shouldn't impact the content you have in your My Places.  If you want to back up your My Places, you can force a save (File menu > Save My Places), and then go find and make a copy of the big myplaces.kml file. If you're on Windows 10, you should be able to find in: C:\Users\<yourUserName>\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth\ or a similar folder. You can also just right-click on the top-level folder in My Places and select "Save Place As", and then save it as a KML or KMZ file (recommend KMZ since it's compressed and should include embedded images, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because of a Google Earth Pro outage earlier this week, which caused most Layers and the Historical Imagery tool to disappear for some people.  You should be able to get them back by using the Repair Tool (in the Help menu) to clear the disk cache.

More info and detailed instructions in this support forum post:
https://support.google.com/earth/thread/74017056

Comment: thanks for your help in fixing this problem. All good now

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Google seems to have proactively moved Borders and Labels, along with Roads and Places to "Outdated". A move likely intended to eliminate duplicate work with maintaining the product alongside Google Maps. Hopefully it does not signal a slow decline in Google Earth's availability.